# Hyperledger Fabric 2.x and Explorer connection

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I run the hyperledger fabric test-network from documentation but How can I integrate hyperledger explorer with it. In documentation of hyperldger fabric there is nothing about UI part. Hyperledger fabric test-network docker containers below. I pull explorer container but I couldn't start also.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS             PORTS                                                                    NAMES
b96963643368   hyperledger/fabric-tools:latest     "/bin/bash"         About an hour ago   Up About an hour                                                                            cli
836a3be4c897   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:9051->9051/tcp, 7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9445->9445/tcp                 peer0.org2.example.com
49564f47ce2b   hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest      "peer node start"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9444->9444/tcp                           peer0.org1.example.com
8957033f991b   hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest   "orderer"           About an hour ago   Up About an hour   0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9443->9443/tcp   orderer.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

There is documentation on how to use Hyperledger Explorer with the *test-network* from the Fabric sample here (although, at the time of writing, I notice that the project has recently been marked "end of life"):

https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer#quick-start-using-docker

If you are looking for a more complete UI-based management experience, it might be worth looking at this Hyperledger Lab project:

https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/fabric-operations-console#readme